# ffmpeg Codec not supported,No capable devices found

Tags: ffmpeg, nvidia, codec

i am using ffmpeg with hevc_nvenc encoder but when i run my command:

```
ffmpeg -loglevel debug -i input.mp4  -c:v hevc_nvenc  out.mp4
```

i get  following error:

```
[hevc_nvenc @ 0x34c3200] Nvenc initialized successfully                                                                                                                                                                                      
[hevc_nvenc @ 0x34c3200] 2 CUDA capable devices found                                                                                                                                                                                        
[hevc_nvenc @ 0x34c3200] [ GPU #0 - < NVIDIA Tesla K80 > has Compute SM 3.7 ]                                                                                                                                                                
[hevc_nvenc @ 0x34c3200] Codec not supported                                                                                                                                                                                                 
[hevc_nvenc @ 0x34c3200] [ GPU #1 - < NVIDIA Tesla K80 > has Compute SM 3.7 ]                                                                                                                                                                
[hevc_nvenc @ 0x34c3200] Codec not supported                                                                                                                                                                                                 
[hevc_nvenc @ 0x34c3200] No capable devices found                                                                                                                                                                                            
[hevc_nvenc @ 0x34c3200] Nvenc unloaded                                                                                                                                                                                                      
Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
```

here is my ffmpeg configuration:

```
  configuration: --enable-nonfree --enable-nvenc --enable-libx264 --enable-gpl --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-cuda-nvcc
```

note: i have no problem when i use "h264_nvenc" but i don't know why it doesn't work with "hevc_nvenc"

Comment: "Codec not supported" is a pretty straightforward error. Your almost 7 year old GPUs are not supported

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tnx to talonmies.

here is the resource if anyone need it:

here you can find your GPU architecture and generation:

```
https://gitlab.pasteur.fr/inception-gpulab/wiki/-/blob/master/nvidia-gpu-hardware-acceleration.md
```

and based on that you can find out nvidia de/encoder supported (264,265):

```
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nvidia_NVENC
```